# Chrome inspector: refresh or keep code while navigating

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

In the chrome console one can interact with the page, example:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
  console.log("my code")
};
```

When I navigate away from the page the code works. But when I navigate again the code doesn't work anymore. Maybe because it needs to be initiated again? I tried that with `window.onload` but that doesn't solve the problem. I also tried ["Custom JavaScript Snippets"](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/authoring-development-workflow#snippets) but all that does is keep code as file, it does not "refresh" or initiate the code.

Comment: Where is this code? Are you just typing it into Chrome dev tools? If so this is not persistent and only lasts until the page changes.

Comment: @MrMisterMan The code is in the question... So basically: how do I persist the code after the page changes

Answer (score 0):

If you're typing this code into dev tools you can't make it persist. What you could do is learn to write [Chrome Extensions](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions) and then install your own extension to always run this code `onbeforeunload`.